# Are the TEXT locators different in android 6.0 and android 7.0 for Alert box?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, android, mobile-automation, seetest

I am facing an issue where TEXT property is in UPPERCASE in Android OS 7 while in OS 6 the same property is shown in Sentence Case for the same application.

[image]

Can anyone suggest why this is happening ? Please share if you have come across the same thing.